# Saving images to a folder in the same directory Python

Tags: python, image, python-requests, python-os

I have written this code that takes a URL and downloads the image. I was wondering how can I save the images to a specific folder in the same directory?

For example, I have a folder named `images` in the same directory. I wanted to save all the images to that folder.

Below is my code:

```
import requests
import csv
    
with open('try.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for rows in csv_reader:
        image_resp = requests.get(rows[0])
        with open(rows[1], 'wb') as image_downloader:
            image_downloader.write(image_resp.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for this?

```
with open(os.path.join("images", rows[1]), 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

See official docs here: [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Requests specific stuff from https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

PS: You might want to use a connection pool and/or multiprocessing instead of the `for rows in csv_reader`, in order to have many concurrent requests.

Comment: @CodeWithAwais - Great to hear. Click the ✓ to accept my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Saving an image can be achieved by using .save() method with Pillow library’s Image module in Python.

Ex.

```
from PIL import Image

file = "C://Users/ABC/MyPic.jpg" # Selects a jpg file 'MyPic'
img = Image.open(file)

img.save('Desktop/MyPics/new_img.jpg') # Saves it to MyPics folder as 'new_img'
```

Image.save(fp, format=None, **params)[source]:

Saves this image under the given filename. If no format is specified, the format to use is determined from the filename extension, if possible.

Keyword options can be used to provide additional instructions to the writer. If a writer doesn’t recognise an option, it is silently ignored. The available options are described in the image format documentation for each writer.

You can use a file object instead of a filename. In this case, you must always specify the format. The file object must implement the seek, tell, and write methods, and be opened in binary mode.

Comment: Could you have a link to the library you've mentioned? The latest version of [`Pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) (the fork of `PIL`) is accessed by using `from PIL import Image`, what version is this that you are using?

Comment: Ah, sry. I was in a bit of a rush and I wrote Pillow instead. I'll fix that.